# HTML form with multiple submit buttons only returns input text arguments of the first button

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to configure an HTML web user interface to control an IoT device. The IoT device can run in two different modes: Schedule or On Demand. I have three buttons separated in two field sets: one button to apply a schedule (start date, periodicity and how long the device runs for every cycle), a second button to disable the schedule and a third to run the device on demand (for a time interval specified in seconds).

“Apply Schedule” button seems to be working and passing the arguments through the URL, but the rest of the buttons seem to be passing the "Apply" arguments.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <style>
  .input-group[class*="col-"] {
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .control-label.multiline {
   padding-top: 10;
  }
 </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
   <h1>Device Control Page</h1>
   <br/>
   <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Schedule</legend>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-1" for="form_name">Start:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_scheduleinterval">
         <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
         </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-1" for="form_name">Interval (seconds):</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_scheduleinterval" value="30">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-1" for="form_name">Repeat every (hours):</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_scheduleperiod" value="24">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class='col-xs-1'>
       <form action='/' method='POST'>
        <button type='button submit' name='apply' value='1' class='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Apply Schedule</button>
        <button type='button submit' name='disable' value='1' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg'>Disable Schedule</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <legend>On Demand</legend>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-1" for="form_name">Interval (seconds):</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_name" placeholder="30">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class='col-xs-1'>
       <form action='/' method='POST'>
        <button type='button submit' name='run' value='1' class='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Run Now</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.en-US.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'en-US'
      });
    </script>
 <script>
      var scheduletimestamp;
      var scheduleperiod;
      var scheduleinterval;
      $('#apply').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        scheduletimestamp = $('#datetimepicker').val();
        scheduleperiod = $('#text_scheduleperiod').val();
        scheduleinterval = $('#text_scheduleinterval').val();      
        $.get('/apply?date=' + scheduletimestamp + '&interval=' + scheduleinterval + '&period=' + scheduleperiod, function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
      });     
    </script>
 <script>
      var ondemandinterval;
      $('#run').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ondemandinterval = $('#text_ondemandinterval').val();      
        $.get('/run?interval=' + ondemandinterval, function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
      });     
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: You can not nest form elements into each other, that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you have a 2 forms inside another form block.  Your "button type='button submit'" will trigger submission of form it belongs to.  From past experience you may trigger the parents form submit procedure. Your onclick events may not stop that from happening.  If you want to submit to various pages, do one form and change submit page when onclick happens, remove button- submit as well, just use buttons then.